# How to use regex for a persons name?

Tags: regex, validation, python-2.7

Basically here is my code and I cannot find the problem with this, So I'm looking for advice.

```
name = raw_input('What\'s your name? ') 
if not re.match(r'[A-Za-z- ]+', name):
    print 'Invalid name.\n' #error message
```

Comment: Obligatory: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). 田中太郎 Smith is going to be very displeased when you tell him his name isn't real.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You must need to add end of the line anchor. Without the anchor `foo?` would be considered as a valid one. That is, it won't print the message `Invalid name` for this name.

```
if not re.match(r'[A-Za-z- ]+$', name):
    print 'Invalid name.\n'
```

**Example:**

```
>>> s = 'foo?'
>>> if not re.match(r'[A-Za-z- ]+', s):
    print('Invalid name.\n')


>>> if not re.match(r'[A-Za-z- ]+$', s):
    print('Invalid name.\n')


Invalid name.
```

Comment: Thanks man I can't believe it was that simple

Comment: SInce you're new to StackOverflow, I suggest you to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: But what exactly does that anchor do in this case just so i know for later use.

Comment: End of the line. This asserts that we are at the end. So no chars would be present after that.

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Why 4 downvotes?

Comment: I dont know why that has happened but the code it working correctly? Message staff mate?